# how to show decimals in sql instead of 0

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal

I am trying to get the percent  and it just shows up as zero. I want to show two decimal places such as 0.65
Here is a piece of the query I am selecting:

```
select count(numbers)/count(othernumbers) decimal(3,2) as"rate"
```

if I use this it shows up as 0 and gets rid of the rest

```
select count(numbers)/count(othernumbers) as"rate"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT FORMAT(this / that, 2) as rate
```

Meanwhile, I question whether `COUNT(numbers)` is what you want.  That counts how many rows have a non-NULL value in the column `numbers`.

Also, fraction is usually more like `x / (x+y)` -- meaning the fraction of the total (x+y) that is x.

A "percentage" needs `100*` somewhere.  13/20 is the *fraction* 0.65 or the *percentage* 65.00 .

Answer (score 3):

need to convert both of your "count(numbers)" and "count(othernumbers)" to decimal also.

```
select  convert(decimal(5,2), count(numbers))
        /
        convert(decimal(5,2), count(othernumbers))
        as"rate"
```

Here's an example that works in SSMS (Sql Server):

```
select Convert(decimal(3,2), convert(decimal(4,2), 1.0) / convert(decimal(4,2), 10.0)) as [rate]
```

Comment: It doesn't in my SSMS: select 1/10 as [rate]

Comment: Since SQL server isn't MySQL.

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

Comment: See my second example, it's because of converting 10 to decimal(3,2), which says only 1 digit left of the decimal, and 10 has 2 digits

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this convert value to Decimal, This will give you the decimal till two places

```
SELECT CONVERT( DECIMAL(10,2),
                    ( CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), numbers) / 
                      CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), othernumbers) ) ) AS rate
```

Comment: you dont even use any column names in this what the?

Comment: numbers & other numbers is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @bigdowg:- you have to use two number as you required instead of numbers & othernumbers. this is just sample way to the query.   If you have issue to implement in your way, show your full query, so that we can resolve that

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked ceil(), floor() and round()

If you want without rounding anything

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(count(numbers)/count(othernumbers),2) as "rate"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate

Comment: Oh sorry , I saw the `mysql` tag that's why

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(decimal(11, 2), 102)

select convert(decimal(11, 2), 102.5)

select convert(decimal(11, 2), 102.74)

select convert(decimal(11, 2), 102.745)
```

> Results:
>   102.00;
>   102.50;
>   102.74;
>   102.75